# Trying to install Atheros AR8161 ethernet driver without internet connection

Tags: networking

I have downloaded appropriate build-essential and linux headers files (and all dependencies....I think) from the internet and placed them on my desktop.

I am now trying to install the Atheros AR8161 driver from this package:
compat-wireless-2012-11-13-pc
Here is the output:

http://paste.ubuntu.com/1364448/

You can see from the code...or it appears to me...that build-essential and linux-headers have been installed properly.

But I am still getting these error messages. Why?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I don't see build-essential and its dependencies in your pastebin. Did you install it previously? What is the status?

```
    sudo dpkg -s build-essential
```

Second, the driver alx doesn't exist in the file you downloaded. Even if it compiled correctly, no alx driver could be built. I suggest you try this: http://www.orbit-lab.org/kernel/compat-wireless-3-stable/v3.5/compat-wireless-3.5.4-1-snpc.tar.bz2

I just compiled it on a 3.2.0-xx kernel for alx with no warnings or errors.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I neglected to include build-essential. I got so caught up in the dependencies, I forgot what they depended on in the first place. I think I have the build and header files installed correctly now. I was attempting to install the compat-wireless-3.5.4-1-snpc.tar.bz2 file you posted and got these errors at the end:  http://paste.ubuntu.com/1367443/

Comment: Wow. Are you running on a USB key or a virtual device or ... ?? I am afraid I am not experienced in GRUB. You may need to start a new question. You should be able to load the alx driver temporarily to test:  sudo insmod /home/ubuntu/Desktop/compat-wireless-3.5.4-1-snpc/drivers/net/ethernet/atheros/alx/alx.ko   The ethernet should come to life. Test: ifconfig  You should have an eth0 interface.

Comment: I am running on USB key. Maybe that is the problem now.

Comment: Sorry I can't help with GRUB. Did the alx driver insmod as expected?

Comment: OK, well, I installed Ubuntu on the hard drive and the compat-wireless module installed beautifully. The computer now recognizes my driver.  This is a HUGE step. Thank you very much indeed.

Comment: OK, no when I went back in there was no driver. I am posting this in a new thread.